# How to assign single value to multiple variable name using let in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to assign one value to all variables names in typescript. But not working .How to assign it.

```
let name1,name2,name3,name4 = false;

console.log(name1,name2,name3,name4);
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-7plax5-gpafmb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I don't think this is possible? Can't think of a single way to do this, as the `,` seperates the names. Not even sure if your are `let`-ing any of the variables apart from the first one?

Answer (score 4):

I would fill an array and destructure it to assign all variables to the same value.

```js
let [name1, name2, name3, name4] = Array(4).fill(false);

console.log(name1, name2, name3, name4);
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't overcomplicate it

```
let name1 = false;
let name2 = false;
let name3 = false;
let name4 = false;
```

It's readable and works well with multiple cursors in your IDE

Comment: not to mention if you're debugging you might want to search for "name4 = " to work out where it gets its value

Answer (score 1):

You can only do it in a 2 liner :

```
let name1,name2,name3,name4;
name1 = name2 = name3 = name4 = false;
console.log(name1, name2, name3, name4)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAdghgtiAjAGlggTK+IDMWEAsA3ALABQaSEAvNNujXQjo5QYwGYzADOIpZAMYB7KD2GgAdMGEBzABSUUTEJhV4VBAJRA)

Comment: Playground contains error(s) 